# Unable to get user groups from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get **user groups** information from Azure Active Directory using below code snippet.

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetUserGroupsAsync(string alias)
{
            var groupList = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IUser userObject = getUserObject(alias);
                Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var grouppages = await ((IUserFetcher)userObject).MemberOf.OfType<Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group>().ExecuteAsync();
                    do
                    {
                        groupList.AddRange(grouppages.CurrentPage.Select(g => g.Mail != null ? g.Mail.Trim() : null).Where(eMail => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eMail)).ToList());
                        grouppages = await grouppages.GetNextPageAsync();
                    } while (grouppages != null);
                });
                t.Wait();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            return groupList;
}
```

Issue: I am getting below exception for **some** users.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException: The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Directory_ExpiredPageToken","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request."}}}
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndExecute[TElement](IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<ExecuteAsync>b__6b[TSource,TInterface](IAsyncResult i)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Please help in resolving this issue. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious enough? Your access token is expired. Btw, you should include `getUserObject` function as well

Comment: Not a very nice way to address a question when someone reaches out for help Hung. I'm having the same issues and it happens right after I authenticate and then immediately try to access groups. However, if I simply try to list the user's name, address etc using the same API I get no token expiration issue. We're just trying to get help so please be nicer and help if you can. I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the exception(`The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request.`) will occur when we are trying to retrieve the group's members page by page however at the same time there are others are manipulating the groups members like adding or deleting.

We need to handle this exception in the code. For example, we can notify the users and info users to retry to get the members after we get this exception.

Comment: Any update on this issue?  We are just now starting to experience this issue.