# Azure AD error : The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Getting below error while reading users from Azure Active Directory group

```
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException: The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Directory_ExpiredPageToken","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request."}}}
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndExecute[TElement](IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<ExecuteAsync>b__6b[TSource,TInterface](IAsyncResult i)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<ExecuteAsync>d__70`2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<ExecuteAsync>d__70`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.PagedCollection`2.<GetNextPageAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.TranslatingPagedCollection`2.<GetNextPageAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
```

using package id="Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452"

Thanks for your help.
Sanjay A.

Comment: Is it possible that another user/system is updating the group members at the same time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650625/unable-to-get-user-groups-from-azure-active-directory

Comment: I don't think so, but I will check on that item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still see the issue? 
Can you please share the timestamp and correlation id of the error which will help us to find out the root cause.

Workaround: Starting enumerating the members of the group again.

Comment: I am not seeing this issue anymore.